# Xcode 8 Says Provisioning Profile Has aps-environment entitlement but after export Archive aps-environment is missing

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

So in Xcode the provision profile says that **aps-environment** entitlement is part of it but after Archive the provisioning profile is missing the **aps-entitlement**.

[image: Xcode screenshot of entitlements]

[image: Organizer when uploading to TestFlight/AppStore]

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. No problem on previous XCode. Apple always change thing and get me lost...

Comment: When I expand my entitlement during archive, I can't even see anything, it's blank. But after I uploaded Apple email to inform that I'm missing Push Notification. I went to my app 'Capabilities' and switched on "Push Notification" and upload again. This time no warning. And I'm able to see the "aps-environment" under "Activity". Hope it works after going thru app store.

Comment: Having the same exact issue HMR. Really looking forward to what the solution is here.

Answer (score 3):

The Xcode 8 release notes mention this issue:

> Xcode 8 does not automatically copy the aps-environment entitlement from provisioning profiles at build time. This behavior is intentional. To use this entitlement, either enable Push Notifications in the project editor’s Capabilities pane, or manually add the entitlement to your entitlements file. (28076333)

In general, any entitlement you intend your app to have should be in your entitlements file.